# Attempt to change static non final field throws IllegalArgument Exception

Tags: java, reflection

Class that has private static non final field

```
package sample;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class App {
   private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

   public void doSomething() {
      logger.error("Cannot do something");
   }
}
```

Attempt to set this field through reflection

```
package sample;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class AppTest {

    @Test
    public void doSomething() throws Exception {
        App app = new App();

        Logger mockedLogger = mock(Logger.class);

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(App.class, "logger", mockedLogger);
    }
}
```

results in IllegalArgumentException

```
Can not set static org.slf4j.Logger field sample.App.logger to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger$MockitoMock$1185285221
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set static org.slf4j.Logger field sample.App.logger to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger$MockitoMock$1185285221
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeStaticObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeStaticObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.setField(ReflectionUtils.java:633)
```

According to JavaDocs of invoked method

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.20.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-

> Set the static field with the given name on the provided targetClass
> to the supplied value.

setting static field is supported.

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to set it with a different logger? Do those two loggers share a common interface?

Comment: You are right, they are not the same interface as I had thought.

Comment: Did you mean to link to https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.20.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object- ?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out, I have edited the question with right link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the IllegalArgumentException is thrown by `java.lang.reflect.Field.set` according to the stack trace, the [javadoc for Field.set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html?#set-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) can be consulted as to the reason.

It states:

> IllegalArgumentException - if the specified object is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying field (or a subclass or implementor thereof), or if an unwrapping conversion fails.

Comparing your provided App and AppTest classes reveals that AppTest imports `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger` whereas App imports `org.slf4j.Logger`

Since you are trying to inject a mock of the logger, change the first import in AppTest to `org.slf4j.logger`.

Comment: After making suggested change, there is no exception.